# Classname of ActiveWindow in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

In my MDI application I'm loading one DialogBar in mainframe.But I want to show that DialogBar when some child window gets invoked(GroupView,TrendView).For other windows it should be hidden(GraphView).So for all functions used to invoke child window from CMainFrame is hiding the DialogBar like this.

```
void CMainFrame::OnGroupview()
{
.
.
.
m_RecentAlarms.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
}
```

For some view

```
void CMainFrame::OnGroupview()
{
.
.
.m_RecentAlarms.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

So,when I click TrendView I get the DialogBar and when I click GraphView the DialogBar gets hidden.But Again when I click TrendView I didn't get Dialogbar. Because the application is multiple window.The previous TrendView is behind the GraphView, when i invoke just it show in front.

So my idea is I have one thread in Mainframe,this function updates some values in all views.In that I will check whether the Active View is TrendView, if it is so then DialogBar will be shown other wise it will be hidden.

I used this..

```
CMDIChildWnd* pChild = ((CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd())->MDIGetActive();
```

But I dont know how to get the active view is TrendView only....

Pls help me in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you have the active window in `pChild`.
Hope you have a member variable corresponding to each view (GraphView, TrendView etc)
I suppose it will be something like: `m_GraphView`, `m_TrendView` etc.
Now what you have to do is compare the handles of both the windows.

Try this code:

```
if( pChild->GetSafeHWND() == m_GraphView.GetSafeHWND() )
{
   m_RecentAlarms.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
}
else
{
  m_RecentAlarms.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW); 
}
```

To compare the handle of the window is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

First, **CMDIFrameWnd::MDIGetActive** gets the active MDI child frame.
Next, you can get its active view by a call of **CFrameWnd::GetActiveView**.
Finally, call **CObject::IsKindOf**.

Example:

```
   CMDIChildWnd* pFrame = ((CMDIFrameWnd*)AfxGetMainWnd())->MDIGetActive();
   if(NULL != pFrame)
   {
      CView* pView = pFrame->GetActiveView();
      if(NULL != pView)
      {
         if(pView->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(TrendView)))
         {
            // The active view is of type 'TrendView'
         }
         else if(pView->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(GraphView)))
         {
            // The active view is of type 'GraphView'
         }
      }
   }
```

Notes:

1. Be sure the view classes have defined DECLARE_DYNCREATE and
   IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE in order to use *IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS...*
2. I posted [here](http://www.codexpert.ro/forum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=1547) related sample code about finding the active view
   in SDI/MDI MFC applications.

Comment: If the comparison is not about a specific instance but just the view type, then I recommend this answer!

Comment: I used this code..It shows the error in MDIGetActive() so used like this **CMDIFrameWnd *pMainWnd = (CMDIFrameWnd*)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd ; CMDIChildWnd *pChild = (CMDIChildWnd*)pMainWnd->GetActiveFrame (); CView *pView = (CView*)pChild->GetActiveView (); if(NULL != pView)** but pView returns NULL.Im using this piece of code in MainFrame Class.